# Android Studio: Rendering problems - The following classes could not be found

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

My problem:

[image]

As I am trying to create an object on my layout that can be differentiated as a view on another class, even though I have named it the exact same as you can see on the other class, android studio keeps telling me there is no such class as DrawingView.

What am I doing wrong?